# Groovy: generate equals and hashCode methods

Tags: java, groovy

If I have a simple Groovy class such as

```
class Address {

  Integer streetNumber
  String streetName
  String state
  String zip
  Country country    
}
```

Although I could write (or use an IDE to generate) `hashCode` and `equals` methods like:

```
boolean equals(o) {
    if (this.is(o)) return true;

    if (!o || getClass() != o.class) return false;

    Address that = (Address) o;

    if (streetNumber? !streetNumber.equals(that.streetNumber) : that.streetNumber!= null) return false;
    if (streetName? !streetName.equals(that.streetName) : that.streetName!= null) return false;
    if (state? !state.equals(that.state) : that.state!= null) return false;
    if (zip? !zip.equals(that.zip) : that.zip!= null) return false;
    if (country? !zip.equals(that.zip) : that.zip!= null) return false;

    return true;
}

int hashCode() {
    int result = (streetNumber ? streetNumber.hashCode() : 0);
    result = 31 * result + (streetName ? streetName.hashCode() : 0);
    result = 31 * result + (state ? state.hashCode() : 0);
    result = 31 * result + (zip ? zip.hashCode() : 0);
    return 31 * result + (country ? country.hashCode() : 0);
}
```

Although this will work fine, I feel I could be making better use of Groovy's dynamism to achieve the same thing in a lot less code. One approach that springs to mind is using `.properties` to get a map of an object's property names and values. I can then iterate over these properties, calling `hashCode()` or `equals()` on each one to achieve the same result as above.

Before I go down this path, I just want to check whether anyone else has found a good solution to this problem. I'm a bit wary of rolling my own solution, because the consequences of messing up `equals()` or `hashCode()` are potentially dire and hard to track down.

Thanks,
Don

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm not a groovy developer, but I understood that from groovy 1.8 you can invoke the AST transformation using @EqualsAndHashCode on the type.

Comment: FYI, this feature is only available in Groovy 1.8-beta-1. Groovy 1.8 is scheduled for release at the end of 2010. See here for details http://groovy.codehaus.org/News

Comment: and note it only considers _properties_ (not fields that have a public/protected/private access modifier) unless you specify *includeFields=true* on the annotation

Answer (score 5):

Or you can just use [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/)'s [`EqualsBuilder`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang/builder/EqualsBuilder.html) and [`HashCodeBuilder`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang/builder/HashCodeBuilder.html). You can either let the builders use Reflection such that it will evaluate all fields or identify which field should be included in the `equals()` and `hashCode()` computations.

They also have a [`ToStringBuilder`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang/builder/ToStringBuilder.html) if you're interested.

Comment: A word of caution - the reflective methods have a significant performance cost, so it is generally better to avoid those.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a purely Groovy solution, you could do something like this:

```
interface DefaultEquality {}

DefaultEquality.metaClass.hashCode = {
    delegate.properties.inject(1) { hash, property ->
        if (property.key == "class" || property.key == "metaClass") {
            hash
        } else {
            31 * hash + (property.value?.hashCode() ?: 0)
        }
    }
}

DefaultEquality.metaClass.equals = { obj ->
    def outerDelegate = delegate
    outerDelegate.properties.inject(true) { equals, property ->
        if (property.key == "metaClass") {
            equals
        } else {
            equals && outerDelegate[property.key] == obj[property.key]
        }
    }
}


class Foo implements DefaultEquality {
    String name
    Integer number
}

def a1 = new Foo()
def b1 = new Foo(name: "Delphyne")
def c1 = new Foo(number: 1)
def d1 = new Foo(name: "Delphyne", number: 1)

def a2 = new Foo()
def b2 = new Foo(name: "Delphyne")
def c2 = new Foo(number: 1)
def d2 = new Foo(name: "Delphyne", number: 1)

assert a1 == a2 && a1.hashCode() == a2.hashCode()
assert b1 == b2 && b1.hashCode() == b2.hashCode()
assert c1 == c2 && c1.hashCode() == c2.hashCode()
assert d1 == d2 && d1.hashCode() == d2.hashCode()
```

You could also implement an AST transformation that does the same thing.  You probably should also check that the classes match, as in a traditional equals() method, but that seems to violate the duck-typing principal to me.  Adjust as your tastes suit you.

Note that if you're in a script, the classes end up being an anonymous inner class inside the script, so the equality would fail anyway.  Normal compiled classes won't suffer this same problem.

Comment: I get a groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property if obj does not have a name or number property.