# Grails: Comparing two unsaved domain class objects always returns false

Tags: grails, groovy, comparison, equals, grails-domain-class

I need to compare several domain class objects while they are still unsaved, however, I always keep getting a false result from the comparison.  Turns out even the following comparison will return false:

```
new DomainClass().equals(new DomainClass())
```

Since both are brand new objects they should both have identical data and should be equal to each other.  Unfortunately the equals method (or the == operator) returns false.  Is there another correct way of performing this comparison?

Comment: This might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1407311/groovy-generate-equals-and-hashcode-methods

Comment: Did the link above helped you? Also, do you need to save them to DB at this moment or not?

Answer (score 3):

Your code same with this:

```
a = new DomainClass();
b = new DomainClass();

a.equals(b)
```

So clearly the test must return false as far as **a** and **b** are not referencing same object.

If you want value based comparing:
*Iterate over the fields and compare them one by one*

Or check here for a [more formal way of doing it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16324827/grails-integration-test-domain-object-equality).

Answer (score 2):

you can use 'spaceship operator' (<=>) which work like compareTo() 
or you can override equals() method in your DomainClass that make able to use this code 
`new DomainClass().equals(new DomainClass())`

to override equals() you can use `@EqualsAndHashCode` annotation
this annotation automatically generate equals() and hashcode() methods
So, you class will look like this:

```
@EqualsAndHashCode
class DomainClass(){
   String field1
   String filed2
   etc
}
```

and  your generated equals method will look like this:

```groovy
public boolean equals(java.lang.Object other)
         if (other == null) return false
         if (this.is(other)) return true
         if (!(other instanceof DomainClass)) return false
         if (!other.canEqual(this)) return false
         if (field1 != other.field1) return false
         if (field2 != other.field2) return false
//         etc
       return true
}
```

For more details look at this http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/transform/EqualsAndHashCode.html